# How do I reliably track child/grandchild processes on a POSIX system?

Tags: linux, unix, process, posix

I have an interesting (at least to me) problem:  I can't manage to find a way to reliably and portably get information on grandchildren processes in certain cases.  I have an application, [AllTray](http://alltray.trausch.us/), that I am trying to get to work in certain strange cases where its subprocess spawns a child and then dies.  AllTray's job is essentially to dock an application to the task tray, which is (usually) specified as a command line for AllTray to invoke (i.e., `alltray xterm` would start xterm, and manage it in AllTray).

Most GUI software runs just fine under it.  It sets the `_NET_WM_PID` property on its window (or a widget library does) and all's well, because `_NET_WM_PID` == `fork()`ed child.  However, in some cases (such as when running `oowriter`, or software written to run under KDE such as K3b), the child process that AllTray runs is a wrapper, be it a shell script (as in OO.o's case) or a strange program that `fork()`s and `exec()`s itself and effectively backgrounds itself, since the parent process dies very early.

I had the idea to not reap my child processes, so as to preserve in the process table the parent process ID for my grandchildren, so that I could link them back to me by traversing the family tree from bottom-to-top.  That doesn't work, though:  once my child process dies and turns into a zombie, the system considers my grandchild process to be an orphan, and `init` adopts it.  This appears to be the case on at least Linux 2.6 and NetBSD; I'd presume it's probably the norm, and POSIX doesn't seem to specify that to be the case, so I was hoping for the opposite.

Since that approach won't work, I thought about using `LD_PRELOAD` and intercepting my child process' call to `fork()`, and passing information back to my parent process.  However, I'm concerned that won't be as portable as the ideal solution, because different systems have different rules on how the dynamic linker does things like `LD_PRELOAD`.  It won't work for setuid/setgid GUI applications either without the helper library also being setuid or setgid, at least on Linux systems.  Generally, it smells like a bad idea to me, and feels quite hackish.

So, I'm hoping that someone has an idea on how to do this, or if the idea of relying on a mechanism like `LD_PRELOAD` is really the only option I have short of patching kernels (which is *not* going to happen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could investigate the possibility of using [process groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) to keep track of, well, process groups.   A process group is a property (just a number) which you can set before forking, and child processes then inherit it automatically.

AllTray can create a new process group for each application started with it.  You can the send signals to all members of the process group.  I suppose the most useful signals here would be TERM and KILL, in order to kill an application managed in AllTray.

I'm not sure if there is a convenient way to figure out if all members of the process group have already exited or not.  You may have to resort to going through the entire process list and call `getpgid` for each process to see if there are any left in the process group.

Note that process groups won't work for applications which create new process groups themselves.  But that's relatively rare and you probably don't need to worry about such applications.

Comment: Hrm.  I'll take a look into this, and see what happens.  The idea sounds good, though.  Is there any reason that creating just a new single process group would be insufficient?  Currently AllTray only manages one application, and it will eventually manage more, but if a single pgid can do the job just to find processes that it should be looking after, that'd be sufficient, I'd think.

Comment: I can imagine this failing with if the wrapper launches a KDE <=3 or >4.3 through kdeinit, or Firefox if it already has other windows open, etc... in these cases, the new window is created by a process in a completely different tree.

Comment: @ephemient I know KDE apps do strange things, and they're one of the cases I am trying to fix.  There's not much I can do about FF or gnome-terminal when there's already a process running, though I have some ideas for trying to get it to do What The User Means, which I *think* is possible.

Comment: Thanks Ville, this was absolutely what I needed to do.  And KDE applications are even weirder than I thought... but I've got 'em (and OOo) working now.  Thanks a bunch!